# Value of result when implementing void methods via DynamicObject

Tags: .net, dynamic, c#-4.0, dynamicobject

I'm looking at the examples for overriding `TryInvokeMember` on `DynamicObject` to implement dynamic method binding. The signature is as follows

```
public virtual bool TryInvokeMember(
    InvokeMemberBinder binder,
    Object[] args,
    out Object result
)
```

Obviously `result` is used to pass the result back to the caller.

Since there is no overload for `TryInvokeMember` without the `result` out parameter, I assume this method must handle void methods as well. In that case are there any guidelines for what `result` should be set to?

The default implementation on `DynamicObject` sets `result` to null, and that would be my default choice as well, but I haven't been able to find any mention of this in the examples. Are there any guidelines for this? Does it even matter what the result is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use null in this case.

There were some similar questions here before: [How do I express a void method call as the result of DynamicMetaObject.BindInvokeMember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835912/how-do-i-express-a-void-method-call-as-the-result-of-dynamicmetaobject-bindinvoke)
This one is about IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, but DynamicObject is just one of its implementations. Shortly, DLR will always return something, it doesn't allow returning void.

I'll see what I can do about MSDN docs. I may add a note about this to the [DynamicObject.TryInvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvokemember%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter, since the result will be ignored anyway...

Comment: That is what I am thinking as well, but I just find it odd that nobody seems to mention it. I have found a few sources that claim result is used to signal if the binding succeeded or not. However, that is what the bool return type is for.